# Invoking mbean method with jmx-console in cluster

Tags: jmx, jboss6.x, mbeans

I have a implemented mbean and I invoke a method using the jmx-console. This works fine.
My question is: How does this behave in a cluster? Do I have to invoke the method on each node or is this automatically done? If it is configurable, than where can I configure it?

Thank you for your answers.